# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, razor

I'm trying to do a very simple username and password validation against a table called users (containinig an `id(int) username(nchar(10)`) and `password(char(32)`) using Razor but I'm encountering this error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' and 'HasherMD5Main'
```

I created a .cs class that does an md5 hash (`HasherMD5Main`) which returns the value passed as a string (please no comments on security, this is not going into any production environments) and I'm hashing the entered password and then doing a lookup in the db.

### Code

```
@{// Initialize page
    var enteredusername = "";
    var enteredpassword = "";
    var ErrorMessage = "";

    // If this is a POST request, validate and process data
    if( IsPost ) {
        enteredusername = Request.Form["enteredusername"];
        enteredpassword = Request.Form["enteredpassword"];
        var hash = new HasherMD5Main( enteredpassword );
        if( enteredusername.IsEmpty() || enteredpassword.IsEmpty() ) {
            ErrorMessage = "You must specify a username and password.";
        }
        else {
            var db = Database.Open( "MyConnectionString" );
            var passwordquery = db.QuerySingle( "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = @0", enteredusername );
            if( passwordquery == hash ) {
                Response.Redirect( "/Success" );
            }
            else {
                Response.Redirect( "/Failure" );
            }

        }
    }
}

@if( ErrorMessage != "" ) {
    <p>@ErrorMessage</p>
    <p>Please correct the errors and try again.</p>
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log In to Your Account</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="enteredusername" name="enteredusername" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="enteredpassword" name="enteredpassword" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="login" /></p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any ideas on how I can simply validate if the hashed password my app comes up with matches the hash stored in the db?

Comment: Convert them both to string via ToString()

Comment: Q: What's with the lack of indentation?  Did SO mess up your formatting, or do you really format your code like that?

Comment: @Arsalan Do you mind giving me an example of using ToString on my variables? I got a method overload error

Comment: @sputn1ck can you get rid of the var's and keep them to their actual types? If you don't know what the type would be, you can debug it and on debugging when you hover the variable, it will show you the type!

Comment: @Arsalan I don't think I have the ability to debug like that in WebMatrix (perhaps in VS I would) I tried this but I can't get it to match (no error is thrown)  if (Convert.ToString(passwordquery) == Convert.ToString(hash))

Comment: @sputn1ck can you print somewhere or alert to see what is Convert.ToString returning for both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that produces the error is:

> if (passwordquery == hash)

hash is your custom Md5 hasher instance

> var hash = new HasherMD5Main(enteredpassword);

while passwordquery is a resultset from the database query [WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

> var passwordquery = db.QuerySingle("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = @0", enteredusername );

What you want to do is to have your MD5 hasher calculate the hash and then compare it to the result value you can extract form the resultset.

Comment: Thank you, I solved that problem now but I still can seem to convert WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to a string so I can do a comparison

Answer (score 0):

if( passwordquery == hash ) 
is the place where error occured.

When you compare something both should finally boiled down to same type before comparing.

Regards,
Pavan.G